# Vue router trouble with nested route

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

Long story short, I want to implement following routes:

- http://localhost/blog
- http://localhost/blog/:category?/:search?/:page?
- http://localhost/blog/article/:slug

So when user enters `/blog`, the list of articles is being presented. When user enters `/blog/:category?`... the list of articles with filters is being presented and when user enters `/blog/article/:slug` then details of article are being presented.

First two routes are using Blog component, and the 3rd one is using BlogPost component. Everything works fine when I click on the url http://localhost/blog/article/slug_of_article, but when I paste it in the url address the page is rendered with blog component as if the url was parsed by the Blog route, not the BlogPost route.

Below is a snippet of my router config:

```
{path: '/blog/:category?/:search?/:page?', name: "blog", component: Blog},
{path: '/blog/article/:slug', name: "blogPost", component: BlogPost}
```

What should I do to make it work the way I want?

Comment: Have you tried flipping the routes, so "/article" is first matched with `/article` instead of `/:category?`? [Vue Router matching priority](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#matching-priority)

Comment: It worked, thank you. I missed the priority part of routing. Could you write this as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because

`/blog/article/slug_of_article` can match both

`/blog/:category?/:search?/:page?` and

`/blog/article/:slug` routes, you have to tell the router which one you prefer to match first.

[The match priority is set by definition order](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#matching-priority), so the earlier route will match first:

```
{path: '/blog/article/:slug', name: "blogPost", component: BlogPost},
{path: '/blog/:category?/:search?/:page?', name: "blog", component: Blog},
```